# AWS: How to Configure Outward Facing Host?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon EC2 instance.  Lets say my public DNS is

```
ec2-54-200-54-33.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I am using this instance to help develop a new website, and I want to map the host

```
dev01.company.com
```

to this instance.  How do I do that?  I think there are at most 2 steps, including mapping the host with the registrar, and possibly something in Amazon.  What are the steps I would need to do to accomplish this?  How do I take all the details of my instance and map the hosts as metioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon recommends using a CNAME record instead

```
dev01.company.com CNAME ec2-54-200-54-33.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

You will also need to open up whatever ports you need accessible to the security group of the EC2 instance (ie `TCP 80 open to 0.0.0.0/0` > this will open to everyone)

Comment: That may be true, but you should justify it with a citation to the documentation.

Comment: I had the system administrator add the CNAME.  Waiting to see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

1) Assign an Elastic IP to your EC2 instance (you can do that through the AWS Management Console).

2) Add an "A" record for "dev01" pointing to that IP, using the tool provided by your domain registrar.